# Why do tabs in PowerShell seem to take up the width of the terminal?

Tags: powershell

When running a program through PowerShell, any tab character takes up the entire width of the terminal, no matter what that width is, no matter what program I run. Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

[image: console printing tab characters wrong]

Comment: That doesn't happen to me.  What os and version?  Anything unusual in your $profile?  What terminal application?  Is the window really 20x3?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, version 10.0.18363 Build 18363. $profile is empty. As far as I can tell, just Windows 10's normal terminal, although this doesn't happen in CMD. It happens regardless of the windows's width, I just shrunk it here so the effect is more obvious.

Comment: Windows 10 1909?  But that's not the default powershell prompt.

Comment: I can confirm that weird behaviour in _Windows 10 Home 1909_ if run ```"Col1`tColumn2`t`tColumn3"``` from an open `powershell` or `pwsh` prompt However, from `cmd` command prompt both ```powershell -noprofile -command """Col1`tColumn2`t`tColumn3"""``` as well as ```pwsh -noprofile -command """Col1`tColumn2`t`tColumn3"""``` run normally (default tab stop every 8th space). Newest _stable_ `pwsh 7.0.1`…

Comment: @JosefZ Hmm, I don't see it in windows 10 1909 enterprise.  The background would only be black in cmd or powershell 7.  It looks more like a bash prompt.

Comment: @js2010 Yeah, sorry, at the time of taking the picture I had a custom prompt in my $profile, but I commented everything in it when you asked and the results were the same

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that I'm using powershell core, but I confirmed that the same thing happens with windows powershell